# Dynamically generate JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to render a disabled button in JSX like below:

```
render: function() {
return (<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>);
}
```

The above code is working fine. But when I am trying like this:

```
render: function() {
var Reo = 'disabled';
return (<button type="button" {Reo}>Click Me!</button>);
}
```

It is giving Unexpected token error. Please explain why this is happening.

Is there any way to dynamically generate JSX. For example like concatenating:

```
'<button type="button" ' + Reo + '>Click Me!</button>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
render: function() {
  var Reo = "disabled";

  return (<button type="button" disabled={Reo === "disabled"}>Click Me!</button>);
}
```

The `disabled` prop on a button is defined as a boolean. This means you can do any boolean check to set the value.